# PHP : Send Email Notification to my email id If 500 internal error found in any page

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm

How can we know 500 internal error occurred in any PHP Script..So i want to received mail notification on my email ID Like

```
500 error found on /home/user/data/xyz.php at 03/05/2014 : 10.20 PM
```

**Note:** I am use WHM/cPanel

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: @bumperbox which code u want?

Comment: Maybe you have written the email sending part and need help detecting a 500 error, or are you expecting us to write a full solution for you? It is not clear what you are wanting, unless you show us the bits you have already.

Comment: I want help only for detecting 500 error

Comment: @bumperbox Yes apache server

Answer (score 1):

With apache you can create a .htaccess file, put a command like this in the htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 500 /path/to/your/email/script.php
```

Every time a 500 error occurs apache will redirect to that file.

Here is a full explanation

http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/custom-error-pages-using-htaccess

and these are the official apache docs

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Thanks but 500 error occurs Apache will redirect to that file...so how can i know in which page 500 error found .........because I want to send path of 500 error page in email notification

Comment: The script should be launched with a set of environment variables starting with REDIRECT_ that should contain the various paths and query strings involved in the error.

Comment: how to get Environment Variable in PHP Script